# setInterVal() method Doesn't work correctly in ASP.NET Core RazoreView

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, countdown

I need to update my predefined time per one second, for that, I made use of `setInterVal()` method which is a `JavaScript` method. It doesn't get updated every second, actually, it doesn't get updated at all, (but showing me the correct result!)

Server side code:

```
        public IActionResult CountDown() {

            var current = DateTime.Now;
            return Json(new { date= current });
        }
```

Client side code:

```
<script>
    var futureTime = new Date("2023-11-13T03:07:35.5381325+03:30").getTime();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/CountDown",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            /////////////////////////////
            var x = setInterval(function () {
                // Get today's date and time
                var countDownDate = new Date(data.date).getTime();

                // Find the distance between now and the count down date
                var distance = futureTime - countDownDate;

                // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
                document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

                // If the count down is finished, write some text
                if (distance < 0) {
                    clearInterval(x);
                    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
                }
            }, 1000);
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It only gets the date from the server once, `var countDownDate` will always have the same value.

Comment: @James Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Not sure what your intention is.  Do you want to be pinging the server every second?  If so, then the ajax part needs to be inside the set interval as well

Comment: No I don't, I need to ping the server once, then showing the left time to users every one second by using `setInterVal()`, for example: first  time:`1d 2h 3m 2s`, then `1d 2h 3m 1s` and so on.

Comment: It’s very difficult to do that with accuracy, the 1000 ms parameter of setinterval is very approximate and will drift over time.  And using the system date can be tampered with by the user. Not to mention varying network conditions

Comment: @James But what if I need to use a `countdown timer` like that to show users how many hours left to make use of the discount!?

Comment: Ok if accuracy isn’t critical.  Create a date on the users system.  Subtract it from the server date and store the time difference in a variable.  Then you can get the current system time in the set interval and add back the difference before displaying it.

Comment: @James Could you tell me what is wrong with my code now? All I want to know is why `setInterVal()` doesn't get executed every one second, I want the outcome to be something like this: `https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp`

Comment: The difference is that their function uses the system clock via new Date().getTime(), which changes every time it’s read.  Yours uses new Date(data.date).getTime() which never changes because data.date is always the date that your server initially sent.